# Filtering pie graph with plotly, Rmd

Tags: r, r-plotly

I am having a problem with filtering a pie chart.
Basically the code I have now creates a list with all the different charts for each of the value i filter.

```
regPlotsA<-map(unique(SpLC1721A$Reg), ~SpLC1721A%>%
                filter(Reg==.x ) %>%
                plot_ly(labels = ~variable, values = ~value, type = 'pie', frame=~Anno)%>%
                layout(title = .x ,
                       xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
                       yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE))%>%
                 animation_opts(
                   redraw = FALSE, frame =3000, transition= 2900
                 )
)
```

What I need to do is turn this code into something with a dropdown from which the user can select the data observed for a specific Reg value and then plot the relative graphic.
I can't apparently do a thing like this on a markdown file, in a **ioslides** presentation, and I feel so stupid.

[Data that I'm working on][1]

```
structure(list(X = c("Piemonte", "Valle d'Aosta / Vallée d'Aoste", 
"Liguria", "Lombardia", "Trentino Alto Adige / Südtirol", "Veneto", 
"Friuli-Venezia Giulia", "Emilia-Romagna", "Toscana", "Umbria", 
"Marche", "Lazio", "Abruzzo", "Molise", "Campania", "Puglia", 
"Basilicata", "Calabria", "Sicilia", "Sardegna", "Piemonte", 
"Valle d'Aosta / Vallée d'Aoste", "Liguria", "Lombardia", "Trentino Alto Adige / Südtirol", 
"Veneto", "Friuli-Venezia Giulia", "Emilia-Romagna", "Toscana", 
"Umbria", "Marche", "Lazio", "Abruzzo", "Molise", "Campania", 
"Puglia", "Basilicata", "Calabria", "Sicilia", "Sardegna", "Piemonte", 
"Valle d'Aosta / Vallée d'Aoste", "Liguria", "Lombardia", "Trentino Alto Adige / Südtirol", 
"Veneto", "Friuli-Venezia Giulia", "Emilia-Romagna", "Toscana", 
"Umbria", "Marche", "Lazio", "Abruzzo", "Molise", "Campania", 
"Puglia", "Basilicata", "Calabria", "Sicilia", "Sardegna", "Piemonte", 
"Valle d'Aosta / Vallée d'Aoste", "Liguria", "Lombardia", "Trentino Alto Adige / Südtirol", 
"Veneto", "Friuli-Venezia Giulia", "Emilia-Romagna", "Toscana", 
"Umbria", "Marche", "Lazio", "Abruzzo", "Molise", "Campania", 
"Puglia", "Basilicata", "Calabria", "Sicilia", "Sardegna", "Piemonte", 
"Valle d'Aosta / Vallée d'Aoste", "Liguria", "Lombardia", "Trentino Alto Adige / Südtirol", 
"Veneto", "Friuli-Venezia Giulia", "Emilia-Romagna", "Toscana", 
"Umbria", "Marche", "Lazio", "Abruzzo", "Molise", "Campania", 
"Puglia", "Basilicata", "Calabria", "Sicilia", "Sardegna", "Piemonte", 
"Valle d'Aosta / Vallée d'Aoste", "Liguria", "Lombardia", "Trentino Alto Adige / Südtirol", 
"Veneto", "Friuli-Venezia Giulia", "Emilia-Romagna", "Toscana", 
"Umbria", "Marche", "Lazio", "Abruzzo", "Molise", "Campania", 
"Puglia", "Basilicata", "Calabria", "Sicilia", "Sardegna", "Piemonte", 
"Valle d'Aosta / Vallée d'Aoste", "Liguria", "Lombardia", "Trentino Alto Adige / Südtirol", 
"Veneto", "Friuli-Venezia Giulia", "Emilia-Romagna", "Toscana", 
"Umbria", "Marche", "Lazio", "Abruzzo", "Molise", "Campania", 
"Puglia", "Basilicata", "Calabria", "Sicilia", "Sardegna", "Piemonte", 
"Valle d'Aosta / Vallée d'Aoste", "Liguria", "Lombardia", "Trentino Alto Adige / Südtirol", 
"Veneto", "Friuli-Venezia Giulia", "Emilia-Romagna", "Toscana", 
"Umbria", "Marche", "Lazio", "Abruzzo", "Molise", "Campania", 
"Puglia", "Basilicata", "Calabria", "Sicilia", "Sardegna", "Piemonte", 
"Valle d'Aosta / Vallée d'Aoste", "Liguria", "Lombardia", "Trentino Alto Adige / Südtirol", 
"Veneto", "Friuli-Venezia Giulia", "Emilia-Romagna", "Toscana", 
"Umbria", "Marche", "Lazio", "Abruzzo", "Molise", "Campania", 
"Puglia", "Basilicata", "Calabria", "Sicilia", "Sardegna", "Piemonte", 
"Valle d'Aosta / Vallée d'Aoste", "Liguria", "Lombardia", "Trentino Alto Adige / Südtirol", 
"Veneto", "Friuli-Venezia Giulia", "Emilia-Romagna", "Toscana", 
"Umbria", "Marche", "Lazio", "Abruzzo", "Molise", "Campania", 
"Puglia", "Basilicata", "Calabria", "Sicilia", "Sardegna"), variable = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("vanno.a.piedi", "usano.mezzi.di.trasporto"
), class = "factor"), value = c(13.8, 16.4, 16.2, 8.6, 17.6, 
8.8, 10.2, 9.9, 12.1, 6.9, 7.9, 11.8, 11, 16.3, 18.2, 18, 17.3, 
12.7, 13, 14.8, 84.2, 82.5, 83.5, 89.5, 82.2, 90.6, 89.1, 89.4, 
87.1, 91.7, 91.4, 86.9, 87.8, 82.6, 80.1, 81, 81.8, 85.9, 85.8, 
84.9, 14.3, 21.3, 14.1, 10.3, 14.9, 10.3, 11, 10.9, 11, 9.5, 
9.8, 10.6, 12.6, 13.4, 17.4, 16.5, 13.7, 15.1, 15.4, 12.9, 84.8, 
77.4, 85, 88.7, 84.6, 88.9, 88, 88.7, 87.7, 89.5, 89.3, 87.1, 
86.4, 85.4, 80.6, 81.9, 83.4, 84, 83.3, 86.2, 11.8, 19.9, 17, 
10.5, 15.9, 9.4, 12.1, 9.9, 11.3, 10.8, 10.7, 11.2, 7.7, 13.4, 
17.1, 15.7, 14, 12.6, 12.8, 14.9, 88.2, 80.1, 83, 89.4, 84.1, 
90.6, 87.9, 90.1, 88.7, 89.2, 89.3, 88.8, 92.3, 86.6, 82.9, 84.3, 
86, 87.4, 87.2, 85.1, 12.1, 19.7, 14.4, 9.6, 19, 6.4, 9, 9.7, 
10.7, 9, 11, 9.5, 13.2, 12.5, 20.3, 14.2, 12.8, 16.6, 13.3, 14.9, 
87.9, 80.3, 85.6, 90.4, 81, 93.6, 91, 90.3, 89.3, 91, 89, 90.5, 
86.8, 87.5, 79.7, 85.8, 87.2, 83.4, 86.7, 85.1, 15.1, 20.4, 15.8, 
12.1, 14.2, 7.3, 8.2, 10.7, 9.8, 10.9, 9.4, 11.5, 13.8, 13.7, 
17.2, 17, 15.5, 14, 11.6, 13.1, 84.9, 79.6, 84.2, 87.9, 85.8, 
92.7, 91.8, 89.3, 90.2, 89.1, 90.6, 88.5, 86.2, 86.3, 82.8, 83, 
84.5, 86, 88.4, 86.9), Anno = c(2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2019, 
2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 
2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 
2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 
2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
2020, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 
2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 
2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 
2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021)), row.names = c(NA, 
-200L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: Hoper that's what you meant cuz i've never used it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Updated based on your comment

I'm assuming that the column named `X` in your `dput` output is supposed to be the `Reg` that you're filtering upon. I changed the name to `Reg` for this answer.

This is one of many ways that you can make this work. You could use Plotly to make this dropdown. However, if you're using RMD, I find it a lot easier to use the many other tools available.

This uses the package `shinyRPG`, but it's not a Shiny runtime (or anything related to Shiny applications). I'm pretty sure this still isn't a CRAN package. You can get this library with `devtools::install_github("RinteRface/shinyRPG")`.

I start by creating style tags to hide all of the plots and add a bit of space between the dropdown menu and the plots. Changing the visibility ensures it will only load with one plot initially. (When combined with the rest of the code.) Then I create the dropdown menu and attach an on-change event.

````
<style>
.js-plotly-plot {
  display: none;
  margin: 20px;
}
</style>


```{r dropdown}
library(shinyRPG)
# create a dropdown menu to change the visibility
tagDrop  <- rpgSelect("piePlot", "Choose a Pie Chart to Visualize", 
                      setNames(LETTERS[1:length(unique(SpLC1721A$Reg))],
                               unique(SpLC1721A$Reg)),
                      multiple = F)
tagDrop$children[[2]]$attribs$onchange <- "getOps(this)"
tagDrop

```
````

Next, I added the graphs.

````
```{r plotters,results='asis'}

htmltools::tagList(map(unique(SpLC1721A$Reg), ~SpLC1721A %>%
                         filter(Reg == .x ) %>%
                         plot_ly(labels = ~variable, values = ~value, 
                                 type = 'pie', frame = ~Anno)%>%
                         layout(title = .x ,
                                xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE,
                                             showticklabels = FALSE),
                                yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE,
                                             showticklabels = FALSE))%>%
                         animation_opts(
                           redraw = FALSE, frame =3000, transition= 2900
                         )
))

```
````

Lastly, I write the code for ensuring the first plot is visible and the on-change event in Javascript. If you run this chunk it won't do anything. You have to knit to execute JS.

````
```{r pickMe,results='asis',engine='js'}
// for the initial load; show only one pie
setTimeout(function() {
  picker = document.querySelectorAll('.js-plotly-plot');
  picker[0].style.display = 'block';
})

// Something selected by user triggers this function
function getOps(sel) {   
  //get ref to select list and display text box
  graphy = document.querySelectorAll('.js-plotly-plot');
  // loop through selections
  for(i = 0; i < sel.length; i++) {
    opt = sel.options[i];
    if ( opt.selected ) {
      graphy[i].style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      graphy[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
}

```
````

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you so much, but i wanted it to be more of a dropdown menu from which the user could select the Region, and then see the chart of that region. And also i am using ioslides, my bad i didn't say it.

Comment: Wow! I swear I read your question. Sigh. I've fixed my answer now. Sorry about that.

Comment: I guess `redraw` should be equal to `TRUE`, in `animation_opts`.

Comment: Hey, thank you so much, i just have a little problem, if you could tell me if it is only me. When i select for example "Liguria", it prints data from "Puglia", doesn't happen only on Liguria tho.

Comment: @LZ112233 I believe the problem is that the data for 2017 and 2018 do not always add up to 100.

Comment: Lombardia in 2019 and none of the locations in 2017 or 2018 equate to a perfect 100; interestingly, Plotly decided to change the values. Liguria 2017: 16.2 & 83.5 in the dataset—plotted 16.2 & 83.8; Puglia 2017: 18 & 81—plotted 18.2 & 81.8. Liguria 2018: 14.1 & 85 in the dataset—plotted 14.2 & 85.8. Puglia 2018 in the data 16.5 & 81.9—plotted it's 16.8 & 83.2. From 2019-2021 Liguria and Puglia's dataset and plot values are an exact match. I think @Brani's on the money here.